# Google Chrome title bar appears blurry using non-Basic Themes

Tags: windows-7, mac, google-chrome, boot-camp, macbook-pro-retina

Running Windows 7 Professional on a Retina MacBook Pro through Boot Camp, any Windows themes that are not "Basic" will result in Google Chrome's UI to appear bloated and blurry, as can be seen in these two pictures (click to view full size):

**Basic:**
[image]

**Aero:**
[image]

Any ideas why this might be/how to fix it? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What resolution are you displaying in?

Comment: 1920x1200, I tried different resolutions including the recommended (2880x1800) and a more Windows-like (1920x1080) and got the same result.
Anyway have updated the images, they are now clearer.